# djutils autodiscover importing command without top level parent, queue_consumer doesn't like it

Tags: python, django, queue

When djutils goes through autodiscover in the *init*, it imports my task "app.commands.task1" and states this as part of the output of the log.

But when I run webserver and try to queue the command, the queue_consumer log indicates that it cannot find the key "**project**.app.commands.queuecmd_task1"

> QueueException: project.app.commands.queuecmd_task1 not found in CommandRegistry

I assume that the fact that the string it is trying to find has "project" prepended is the reason it cannot find the task.

Why would that be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like duplicate imports in my project were causing the problems.